# How can I display an images from url in react native with an array.map?

Tags: image, react-native, url

I use this code which I found online  https://github.com/nathvarun/React-Native-Layout-Tutorial-Series/blob/master/Project%20Files/12%20Tinder%20Swipe%20Deck/%232%20Complete%20Animation/App.js
I want to use this code with image urls. The problem when I change in the Users array the first uri:"https://URL".I didn't catch an error but the image not show.

```
const Users = [
      { id: "1", uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg'},
  { id: "2", uri: require('./assets/2.jpg') },
  { id: "3", uri: require('./assets/3.jpg') },
  { id: "4", uri: require('./assets/4.jpg') },
  { id: "5", uri: require('./assets/5.jpg') },
]    

My whole code is too long but above is change, the other code is the as in github.
```

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Image source/>` prop expects an object like this `{ uri: 'https://' }` instead of a string. You can read about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#source-as-an-object).

Comment: please write an example like a second line

Comment: `{ id: "1", uri: { uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg' }},`